# After X iterations, the entire application crashes without any exceptions (Error code 0x3) C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

This is my first question on this awesome forum, excuse me if its in the wrong place.

So I'm working on an C# UWP (using .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Standard 2.0) Application.

I'm using it as intended and everything works fine but exactly at the 23 times editing an item inside the app, it crashes, throwing no exceptions and nothing on the Diagnostic tools. (No spike on memory or CPU usage).

The only message is : `The program '[XXXXX] App.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I cannot sure what is wrong with your program. Could you please provid us with some detailed code to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer it's actually a pretty big one and we found out that it was memory related (very bad coding practices)